# Resources for Sutta study/discussion for beginners

Tags: sutras

What texts would you recommend for sutta discussion sessions, where a majority of the participants will be new to discussing suttas? 
with metta

Answer (score 2):

This is my standard recommendation for beginners:
a)Read BuddhismCourse. (Take about 12 hours to read and give you a good idea about the teaching)
http://www.urbandharma.org/pdf/PDF_BuddhismCourse/

b)Print a copy of this Dhamma Chart and refer to it while studding Buddhism.
http://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=16785

c) Read Buddha’s Teaching by Narada. Start from chapter 15.
http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/buddh ... gsurw6.pdf

d) While you reading above texts please listen to the following Dhamma Talk by Joseph Goldstein.
http://www.dharmaseed.org/teacher/96/talk/6162/
e) Start reading Sutta.
Good starting point would be to read Bikkhu Bodhi’s “In the Buddha’s Word”
Then read Sutta Central. Start from Majjhima Nikaya. https://suttacentral.net/m

Answer (score 1):

If you would listen to [nirapekshathwayemaga](http://www.nirapekshathwayemaga.com/) Season 8 - (there are 30 video clips in all), you will get to learn the Dhamma with all the relevant sutta references. These 30 sermons are of such importance, that I am going to translate the contents into English in the near future. I will launch a brand new website "A MEDITATIVE LIFE", for the benefit of all within one year.

Answer (score 1):

Mukhapatha is the best. So easiest way is listen directly from pa-auk teachers.

The tipitaka memorizers can teach [Beginner's Buddhist Course Syllabus By Ancient Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/21056/10100) easier more than try to done it yourself.

You have many other ways more than mukhapatha, but if they will been the best way to teach, the buddha will used them. **But he never.**